# UIBarButtonItem style ignored?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I've been struggling with some weird bar button item behavior for some time now. For some reason the bold style disappears when the "OK" button is klicked on a alert. I've had this behavior when doing other stuff like presenting a modal view controller and dismissing it as well. Why is the bar button item changing its font weight from bold to regular?

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

My settings:

[image]

The weird behavior (before)
[image]
After:
[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as Bordered style.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Bordered style is what's preset when creating a Bar Button Item

Comment: There is such a thing, it's just been deprecated since iOS7.

Comment: What should I use instead? My deployment target is iOS 8 and I get no warnings

Comment: One of the other styles, probably Plain.

Comment: Plain gives me this warning: Plain Style unsupported in a Navigation Item

Comment: Try Done then, as that's what you're setting for the system item. I don't really use IB so can't help much. Usually I would programatically create a button item with either a style or a system item, not both.

Comment: Exactly as @JamesP says. If you want bold, which is the Done style, you should be using the Done style. Combining system Done with Bordered style makes no sense.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see how that's the solution. What about the other buttons that should not be bold? Setting them to "Plain" will give me a warning. And why is "Bordered" there of there is no such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The System Item `Done` button expects to be using the Done style. Combining System Item `Done` with the Bordered style makes no sense.